# Javascript : how to set "setExperimentalOption" for chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium

Getting "options.setExperimentalOption is not a function" error message when using setExperimentalOption.

```
var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
        let options = await new chrome.Options();
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Arrays.asList("disable-popup-blocking","enable-automation")); 
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments('--ignore-certificate-errors');
        options.addArguments('--ignore-ssl-errors');
        
        driver = await chrome.Driver.createSession(options);
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Selenium 4, based on this [api-docs](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/chrome_exports_Options.html), there is `excludeSwitches` method for corresponding experimental option.

```
var chrome = require("selenium-webdriver/chrome");
let options = await new chrome.Options();
options.excludeSwitches("disable-popup-blocking", "enable-automation"); 
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
options.addArguments('--ignore-certificate-errors');
options.addArguments('--ignore-ssl-errors');

driver = await chrome.Driver.createSession(options);
```

And there is a list of methods for other options:

```
this.headless() → Options
this.setChromeBinaryPath( path ) → Options
this.setChromeLogFile( path ) → Options
this.setChromeMinidumpPath( path ) → Options
this.setLocalState( state ) → Options
this.setMobileEmulation( config ) → Options
this.setPerfLoggingPrefs( prefs ) → Options
this.setUserPreferences( prefs ) → Options
this.windowSize( size ) → Options
```

Comment: Its working... Thanks Max.